# How to remove space between bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

in the image there a image , how to remove it?
I'm using bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: no ! i want to remove the space